# How to set Input Parameters when making Service Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

So I'm working on a small example on how to make a service call to a specific web service. I'm using the openweathermap.org web service. The link to this service is the following:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

According to this link, I can search weather by city name. **So I'm able to retrieve and NSLog the JSON data with the following code:**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:WXFORECAST, LOCATION];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

This does the bare minimum and retrieves the service. **Now I would like to get my specific city instead of London.**

If not, I would like to get JUST THE WEATHER part instead of getting the wind speed, and all that other garbage.

Here is the link for details on the API:

http://openweathermap.org/API#weather

Under that link there's a section that says this:

Restriction output:
To limit number of listed cities please setup cnt parameter api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=57&lon=-2.15&cnt=3

I believe this might be what I'm looking for but I don't know exactly how to use it...

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is accessed with a URL, try playing with this in your browser:

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New+York,us

See how I have a plus sign between "New" and "York"? That's to make sure the URL is valid, because they don't allow for spaces.

You have to figure out a way to get the URL you want in your variable. In your code, it's creating the URL using a format string stored in WXFORECAST. So, update that.

I don't have time to read through all of how that API works, but it's possible that you can't request that it gives you less information. But there's nothing stopping you from taking only what you need from it. It's all in that JSON dictionary, if you wanted to get the temperature your code might look like this.

```
NSArray *list = json[@"list"];
NSDictionary *london = list[0];
NSDictionary *main = london[@"main"];
NSString *temp = main[@"temp"];
```

Comment: Sorry but the that code returns nil. I tried doing it by getting "description" but it still returned nil.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean. I had to access "weather" which gave me description....thanks!